# Monodevelop debugging - show return value of a nested expression?

Tags: c#, debugging, monodevelop

I believe this function in Visual Studio is in "Autos" windows. I want to see the value/contents of `GetCurrentLine()` or `Groups` on this line:

```
string str = re.Match(GetCurrentLine()).Groups[0].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Put a breakpoint on the declaration of the string
2) Split the command in 2:

```
string currLine = GetCurrentLine();
string str = re.Match(currLine).Groups[0].Value;
```

Everything should then be visible just by hovering over the values in the IDE or in the 'Locals' watcher.

Comment: Nooo, what if I also want to see what is in Groups or a specific Group? I don't want to edit the code, declare a new variable with a corresponding type (here I don't even care about it) and run it, edit and run it and over again. I could just WriteLine it, then. I don't think this is how debugging is supposed to work.

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318663/how-can-i-add-variables-to-the-watch-window